# How can I CONCAT fields from different independent tables in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm getting form data and using it to fetch them individually and then concat. My current query is this:

```
$design_code = $_POST['design_num'];
$design_code .= ':'.$db->single('SELECT code FROM '. table_brands .' WHERE id=?', [$_POST['brand']]);
$design_code .= ':'.$db->single('SELECT code FROM '. table_types .' WHERE id=?', [$_POST['type']]);
$design_code .= ':'.$db->single('SELECT code FROM '. table_quality .' WHERE id=?', [$_POST['quality']]);
$design_code .= ':'.$db->single('SELECT code FROM '. table_sizes .' WHERE id=?', [$_POST['size']]);
```

All the POST data are independent and hence cannot be joined. What can be a proper replacement query to merge them in one.

PS: `$db->single()` basically sends one single field value.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: @jarlh all these tables have common columns: id, name, code, status. Code is unique field.

Comment: @SaurabhGujarani there is no connection between tables.

Comment: We still need some sample table data and the expected result...

Comment: Perhaps you simply want to UNION ALL the queries?

Comment: @jarlh let's say there are two tables: brand and type. Both of these have fields `id` PK AI, `name` NN, `code` UN. Please check: https://pastebin.com/qGmp8ZKq

Comment: @KshitijKumar :- Please check below answer I have update as per your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select (select code FROM  table1 where id = 1 ) as code1, (select code FROM  table2 where id = 1 ) as code2, table3.code3 FROM table3 where id = 1
```

The result will get in a single row.

And using UNION query the result will come in more than one row.

**EDIT**

Update query as per your last comment "Please check: pastebin.com/qGmp8ZKq"

```
select (select code FROM  brand where id = 2 ) as code1, type.code FROM type where id = 6
```